# Modify HTML Tags for HTML in a variable not the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alright,

I think this is a random question. I was unable to find it while searching on here. Maybe my wording was off. Anyway. this is what I need. I have some html that I obtained from an element using the `outerHTML` method. It is stored in a variable

```
objCodes.refDocs
```

Now that contains just html. What I need to do is modify the html within that variable. I need to change out the id that is in one of the div tags. The div id is random (created by a repeater is ASP.NET) so I need to use a selector like the following `[id^=dvSearcher]`. I've tried doing the following but it didn't do anything to my `objCodes.refDocs html`.

```
$(objCodes.refDocs).find('[id^=dvSearcher]').attr('id', 'newID');
```

Is there a way to just modify the html in that variable ? I can extract the element by just using the find method and setting it to a variable. I just need to modify that one part though.

Any help would be appreciated:-
Thank you.

Comment: is it a chunk of html, or a whole document? if it's a chunk: $("<div>").html(objCodes.refDocs).find('[id^="dvSearcher"]').attr('id', 'newID');

Comment: Is `objCodes.refDocs` a string?

Comment: yes objCodes.refDocs is a string. Which contains html. In that html has that id that I need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the fact you are not storing the newly updated string back into the variable.

The string will not get updated, you need to do it.

```
//What you are doing

var objCodes = {
    refDocs : '<div><div id="dvSearcher"></div></div>'
};

var html = $(objCodes.refDocs);
html.find('[id^=dvSearcher]').attr('id', 'newID');
console.log("I was changed: ", html.html());  //shows updated code
console.log("My value: ", objCodes.refDocs);  //show orginal

//What you need to do
var updatedHTML = $("<div/>").html(objCodes.refDocs);
updatedHTML.find('[id^=dvSearcher]').attr('id', 'newID');
objCodes.refDocs = updatedHTML.html();
console.log("new string: ", objCodes.refDocs);  //updated html string
```

Other option is to store the DOM into the variable and than that will keep the changes.

```
var objCodes2 = {
    refDocs : $('<div><div id="dvSearcher"></div></div>')
};
objCodes2.refDocs.find('[id^=dvSearcher]').attr('id', 'newID');
console.log("The DOMish way: ", objCodes2.refDocs.html());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z5yS/)

Comment: Ahhh, sorry I didn't see the code portion. Yes, that works. Then I can just assign it back to using objCodes.refDocs = html.html(). Perfect. Thank you!